# Is it possible to have multiple video drivers on the same OS?

Tags: x11, drivers, graphics

My desktop has an nvidia graphics card, and I want to clone my installation to boot onto another machine, with integrated AMD graphics. If I install multiple drivers, one for my GPU and another for the other machine's, will that confuse X or will it know which one to use? I know *very* little about X or how it interacts with video drivers, or if this is even a question about X.

Thanks!

Comment: You haven't said anything about your system, but yes, usually you have many drivers. X will use the one that claims to be able to handle the card.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Is it dependent on my system? It's running an RTX 2060 with proprietary drivers right now. The alternate system has a 2700U with integrated RX Vega 10 graphics. I know nouveau and proprietary have many issues with each other, but is that just because they both support the same cards? I _really_ don't want to install a driver and then be unable to start X. thanks